Texture doesnt work well
I want to draw a building, but it doesn't show me the texture correctly.
As you can see in the pictures, it is only one side where the texture is distorted.
The first wall worked without any problems. The problem only occurs when I extrude to another side.
With the second wall, only the front texture is not OK, the back is OK.

Update:
I saw, that in the UV Editing the selected texture is moved. Can I somehow fix the selection?

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"
